# how to test connectivity to the web service?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

In java i have created a JAX- web service, which is up and running, my client connects to the web service.

1. if web service is up, it works fine. but if my web service is not
   up, it should show some message to the client about that issue.
2. in java how can i implement this functionality.
3. My server should show a proper message on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the web service is not up, it cannot provide any functionality. The client will probably recieve an HTTP error (like 404 - not found or 500 - Internal server error) or a timeout.

To display a useful message to the end user you would need to create a client application through which your web service is accessed. The client application could display appropriate messages in case the service could not be reached. An example of creating a simple JAX-WS client can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html).

If the service is up, but cannot handle the request, then you could provide a meaningful error in the response by throwing a GenericSoapFault with the error message as argument.

Comment: what if the service only opens a method that changes database?

Comment: I think you might be lost, Mohican.